# SVG textPath not rendering when generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

For [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) I wrote a little plugin adding textPath functionality. The plugin is very concise:

```
// textpath plugin
SVG.TextPath = function() {
    this.constructor.call(this, SVG.create('textPath'))
}
SVG.TextPath.prototype = new SVG.Element
SVG.extend(SVG.TextPath, {
    text: function(text) {
        while (this.node.firstChild) this.node.removeChild(this.node.firstChild)
        this.node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
        return this
    }
})
SVG.extend(SVG.Text, {
    path: function(d){
        var textPath = new SVG.TextPath().text(this.content)

        while (this.node.firstChild) this.node.removeChild(this.node.firstChild)

        this.track = this.doc().defs().path(d)
        this.node.appendChild(textPath.node)
        textPath.attr('xlink:href', '#' + this.track)

        return this
    }
})
```

To create the same output as [this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath), the plugin can be used as follows:

```
// example usage
var draw = SVG('canvas').viewbox(0, 0, 1000, 300)

var text = draw.text('We go up, then we go down, then up again')
text.font({ size: 42.5, family: 'Verdana' })
text.path('M 100 200 C 200 100 300  0 400 100 C 500 200 600 300 700 200 C 800 100 900 100     900 100')

draw.use(text.track).attr({ fill: 'none', 'stroke-width': 1, stroke: '#f09' })
```

Here is a fiddle of the dynamic version:
http://jsfiddle.net/wout/LNuWM/

But this is where it goes wrong because the text is not rendered. At first I thought something was wrong with my code but when I copied the svg output from the inspector and pasted in a svg document, the text is rendered as expected.

Here an example of the static version:
http://jsfiddle.net/wout/ZbM7K/

Is this a browser glitch or am I missing something?

UPDATE:
This has now been resolved:
http://jsfiddle.net/wout/LNuWM/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an error in SVG.js. The SVG root element gets messed up because of adding the XLink namespace:

```
<svg style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;left:0px;top:0px;"xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ...
---------------------------------------------------------------^
|
--------this should read [SPACE]xmlns:xlink=
```

Comment: As it turns out it was a combination of two mistakes, both to do with wrong usage of namespaces. The xlink declaration in svg.js was set linke this `attr('xmlns:xlink', SVG.xlink, SVG.ns)` instead of `attr('xlink', SVG.xlink, SVG.ns)`, which is obviously the correct way. Additionally, the `xlink:href` attribute on the textPath was set with `setAttribute` instead of `setAttributeNS`, so I changed this `attr('xlink:href', '#' + this.track)` to `attr('href', '#' + this.track, SVG.xlink)`. That did the trick. The textPath implementation is now part of svg.js: http://jsfiddle.net/wout/yfGjF/

Comment: Ah, the good ol' `setAttributeNS`. I am not very unhappy, that I rarely need it at my dayjob. (Although I quite like XML namespaces.)